# how do i fix this bug in the scanner class?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i tried to make a currency converter with the java.util.scanner class :

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class usd_to_inr {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        double r;
        scanner q = new scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("how many dollars you have?");
        float d= sc.nextFloat();
        r = d * 82.20;
        System.out.println("you have" + r + "rupees");

    }
}
```

but this strange error message showed up

```
ab.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        scanner q = new scanner(System.in);
        ^
  symbol:   class scanner
  location: class usd_to_inr
ab.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        scanner q = new scanner(System.in);
                        ^
  symbol:   class scanner
  location: class usd_to_inr
ab.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        float d= sc.nextFloat();
                 ^
  symbol:   variable sc
  location: class usd_to_inr
```

what did i do wrong?

Comment: CaPiTaliZatiOn matters. It's `Scanner`, not `scanner`.

Comment: This is not a bug, it is a compiler error. And even if it was a bug, it would not be a bug in the `Scanner` class, it would be ***a bug in your code***.